# Deleting items from array within for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova

I'm facing a javascript problem with deleting items in an array within a for loop.

My code is checking the existence of a localStorage item containing a stringified object, parse it, run the for loop, do some stuff (that works great) on each item,  delete the item if conditions are good, and finally save the new array to the localStorage item.
Here it is :

```
if (localStorage.getItem(user_id+"_tosave") && localStorage.getItem(user_id+"_tosave").length>1){ 
    var local_tosave = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user_id+"_tosave")); 
    if (local_tosave.length>0){         
        for (i = 0; i < local_tosave.length; i++) {             
            // SOME OTHER STUFF HERE...
            if (navigator.onLine){local_tosave.splice(i,1);}                    
        };          
        localStorage.setItem(user_id+"_tosave",JSON.stringify(local_tosave));
        alert(localStorage.getItem(user_id+"_tosave")); // DISPLAY TO CHECK
    }           
}
```

Only the last item of the array is deleted... why is that ? The splice function breaks the loop when there's more than one element in the array.
I guess there's something about object & iteration as i saw in other conversations but the solutions given didn't work for me.
Fyi, i tried `local_tosave.splice(i--,1);` which was even worse.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are expecting that the array should be empty... right?

Comment: depending on navigator online or not.. i can't automaticaly empty/remove the array after the loop, if that's what you have in mind

Comment: yes depending on navigator.onLine... Put a console.log so that you can track whether it iterates for all indexes or only for the last element.

Comment: i'm on a cordova project so i test on mobile phone and put some alert to see how the loop behaves (rather than console.log). It's ok when navigator's offline (->no splice executed), but when it's online, the first use of splice method breaks the loop.
Weird thing is it works properly in a standard desktop web browser

Comment: okay, then for testing purpose comment navigator.onLine and check whether it makes the array empty or not . If yes then problem is on navigator.onLine i.e it is not working properly on mobile browser or may be this function could not detect the network property properly.So you have to add network information cordova plugin,from there you can get the onLine and offLine methods.

Comment: yes i tried without navigator.onLine and the error is still here, the problem is the splice method apparently

Comment: just try this instead of for loop 
   while(fruits.length > 0){
        if (navigator.onLine){
          fruits.splice(0,1);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to walk array backwards, if order doesn't matter. Like this

```
for (i=local_tosave.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

so the elements on the end would be chopped off and the rest of array would be untouched.

hope it helps

Comment: Looping backwards is a good plan, but "elements on the end" doesn't quite make sense given that it may be that only elements near the start get removed.

Comment: "on the end" - relatively to the next cursor positions

Comment: Looping backwards is the right solution for my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the increment. I suggest to use an other loop with `while`.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < local_tosave.length) {
    if (navigator.onLine) { 
        local_tosave.splice(i, 1);
        continue;                  // because i should stay
    }
    i++;
};
```

Comment: pleas add the content of `local_tosave` an some value for `navigator.onLine`.

Comment: navigator.onLine returns true or false, and local_tosave is something like this `var local_tosave = [{img_local : "first", cat_id : "1"}, {img_local : "second", cat_id : "1"}];`

Comment: Indeed, it works in standard web browser but not in the mobile application (this is a cordova project). Same behavior (error) on iOS and Android

Comment: on mobile, i can not help, sorry.